# IIIF implementation (Loris + Mirador)

Tags: image, iiif

I am trying to implement the IIIF standard in order to show some papyri. I have configured Loris as an image server (here there is an info.json example: https://philhist-papyri-01.philhist.unibas.ch/loris/1/images/1.RectoIliad19th(T)book-IR-enh.jpg/info.json) and also I have configured Mirador. I am also serving manifests via an API (example: https://philhist-papyri-01.philhist.unibas.ch/api/iiif/11b4ca60-6bac-11eb-a1e6-005056b34690/manifest).

When I try to load the images in Mirador, I am getting an error:

> Tile push../node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js.$.Tile failed to load: https, https://philhist-papyri-01.philhist.unibas.ch, philhist-papyri-01.philhist.unibas.ch/6%2Fimages%2F6.VersoUnidentifiedLiteraryText-IR.jpg/full/4,/0/default.jpg - error: Image load aborted

Does anybody have any idea why this is coming from? The image actually can be retrieved from the URI in the manifest (https://philhist-papyri-01.philhist.unibas.ch/loris/1/images/1.RectoIliad19th(T)book-IR-enh.jpg/full/full/0/default.jpg), but it is not being shown in the mirador window.

There might be an issue with the resolver of Loris which is causing the @id of the image not to be canonical, but I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing an issue that perhaps [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is not enabled for your info.json responses.

See: https://projectmirador.org/embed/?iiif-content=https://philhist-papyri-01.philhist.unibas.ch/api/iiif/11b4ca60-6bac-11eb-a1e6-005056b34690/manifest

Depending on how you use Loris to serve content, you will need to [enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) for the IIIF requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I solved the issue. The problem was at the configuration of Loris as it was not getting the image id properly and that is why the manifests were not loaded.